# Dotnet ef migration incorrect syntax

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm developing in .Net Core 2.2 with Postgresql ver 10.11. The solution contains several projects with MVC as the startup project, Core contains all the models, and Data contains the mapping and migrations.

When I tried to run the following line in command prompt it returns "The syntax of the command is incorrect" but I had tried a similar command on the same project before and it worked. Also I have CDed to the newProject directory in cmd.

Anyone has any idea?

```
dotnet ef migrations add updateMapping --startup-project <newPorject.MVC\newPorject.MVC.csproj> --project <newPorject.Data> --context <newProjectContext>
```

Comment: Try to remove < and >.

Comment: @Miamy you saved my life, can't believe it's that simple